# Vue.js click on component triggered multiple times

Tags: vue.js, azure-maps

I'm working with [vue-azure-maps](https://github.com/rickyruiz/vue-azure-maps) to display polygons on a map and I have a problem using the **@click** event on a layer. Here's my template which display the polygon called **cabstand** :

```html
<div :key="'cabstand-' + cabstand.properties.id" v-for="cabstand in cabstands">
  <AzureMapPolygonLayer :key="'cabstandLayer-' + cabstand.properties.id" :options="{
    fillColor: 'rgba(178, 34, 34, 0.1)',
    fillOpacity: 0.1
  }" @click="clickCabstand($event, cabstand.properties)" />
  <AzureMapPolygon :coordinates="getCabstandCoordinates(cabstand)" />
</div>
```

And my **@click** function (just for debugging) :

```js
clickCabstand(e, cabstand) {
  console.log(e)
  console.log(cabstand)
}
```

When I click on a polygon, it triggers a click for each polygon I have on the map but I want to trigger the click on the only polygon I'm clicking on. I already tried to put the **@click** function on the `<AzureMapPolygon>` component but nothing happened (maybe because the layer is in front of the polygon ?)

Thanks,

Comment: `$event.stopImmediatePropagation()` works?

Comment: I added ```e.stopImmediatePropagation()``` in my **clickCabstand** function, and I got this error : ```TypeError: e.stopImmediatePropagation is not a function```

Comment: Called ```e.originalEvent.stopImmediatePropagation()``` and no error, but still clicking every polygon.

Comment: Can you somehow share a small reproducible example via codesandbox.io?

Comment: I found the problem but not the solution yet. I can't define layer coordinates, so I have a lot of layers taking all the map, so when I click anywhere, it click on every layers...

Comment: Did you take a look at Azure Maps Code Samples and see if it can help you get unblocked? https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net

Comment: I solved the problem by creating one data source by layer. :)

Comment: Takachi, can you add the answer to help others.